# Cannot edit tasks (TODO/FIXME/XXX) in eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, task, todo

I am working with IDE Eclipse for android developing with java. I have just shown tasks view, but have a problem. When I select necessary task and open properties, "priority" list-box and "completed" check-box are not active. Why?

*Updated:* I can't post images due to zero reputation, so : [screenshot(zippyshare)](http://www66.zippyshare.com/v/97729095/file.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are at the right properties. If you are really on eclipse you should be able to click on Window/Preferences and see this window:

[image: Preferences Window]

Expand the options like you see it at the screenshot. Here you actully should be able to edit your tasks!

If you want to change the priority, click on the left side of the editor and click on add task. With this task you are able to click on complete and change the priority. For more information look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_task_management.htm).

Comment: Sorry, I mean a view, not that properties
I can't post images due to zero reputation, so : http://www66.zippyshare.com/v/97729095/file.html

Comment: Well I can't change that too... I think it isn't mad for editing the priority? You have to go to your task view and make a right click on it than add task. Than you are able to change priority and are able to click on copleted

Comment: I think, it must not work so. For what reason there is no way to set "completed" for mine TODO-task? :(

Comment: @user2653714 Look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_task_management.htm) it is the descripton from eclipse and his Task Tags I don't find anything to use //TODO and change the priority from it but you are able to click at the left editor bar and add a task to it